# Cordova local notification sound not working

Tags: cordova, notifications, local

My app was working fine for some days and now it's not playing sound but the notification is working fine.
Also i have to delete the emulator in which the sound was working and this is the problem in other emulator which i have created afterwards

This is the warring in the console.

onLoadSoundEffects(),  error -1 while loading samples

any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first uninstall your app and restart your emulator and then it will work fine

Comment: thanks for your answer :D
i was able to start my app

Comment: that's great man hope in future you will learned very well :D